# Можно ли (и как если да) записывать и считывать в xml документ не текстовую информацию средствами Qt?

Tags: c++, xml, qt5

Сразу извинюсь, если некоторые мои формулировки покажутся неккоректными.

Хочу записать в `xml` файл массив байт, представленный `char[100]`, но тут возникла проблема: как это корректно сделать? Использую `QDomDocument` и не понимаю как верно записать эту последовательность байт в ноду `xml`, так как для создания текстовой ноды используется метод `createTextNode(QString)`. Можно конечно сделать вроде того:

```
char buf[100];
QString alfa{buf};
dom_doc.createTextNode(alfa);
```

Но дело в том, что данные в массиве чаров не являются текстом и там могут быть нулевые байты, которые тоже нужно записать в файл. Но если сделать так, как показано выше, то байты после первого нулевого будут отсечены и не войдут в `QString`. Как записать данные корректно?

Comment: Ну закодируйте - хоть простым шестнадцатеричным представлением, хоть base64...

Comment: к сожалению в явном виде байты хранить нельзя. Вы ограничены кодировкой xml-документа, которая `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`, кроме того при хранении текстовой информации необходимо кодировать спец-символы xml-документа < - &lt; > - &gt; & - &amp; (кроме секций CDATA). Для хранения байтовой информации подойдет любая кодировка, для Qt это все умеет QByteArray, ::toBase64() ::fromBase64()